# Does wordpress.com appears in the URL if I buy custom domain service from WP.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, domain-mapping

Let's say I buy a custom domain myblog.com and I host at wordpress... if I access the dashboard page on my blog, will it have wordpress.com in the URL?

I want to be able to manage my blog behind school firewall.. thanks

Comment: How does your school firewall work?

Comment: I dunno anything about that ;) they probably block *wordpress.com*

Comment: I'm guessing it just blocks anything matching *.wordpress.com

Comment: So you probably should ask your question more directly, like: How can I run a blog on worpdress.com even if my schools firewall is blocking *.wordpress.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- try blogging by email
- have your analytics and stats on google analytics or outside source
- have comments emailed to you

that will leave very few things to be done thru administration

to bypass security system try VPN or use of proxy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, administration will still be under the wordpress.com subdomain.

While content will be domain mapped, administration is done through your wordpress.com subdomain - and attempts to access `wp-admin` under your mapped domain will redirect to the wp.com subdomain.

Comment: shame. Any idea how to fix/buypass that?